# Authentication not working in yii2

Tags: yii2-basic-app, yii2-user

1. I have Employee table whose structure is as follows:

EmpId
FirstName
LastName
Username
Password

2. Now in application component I have included my custom class as follows:

   'user' => [
               'identityClass' => 'app\models\Employee',
               'enableSession' => true,
           ],
3. I have implemented foll methods in Employee model as follows:

   public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
   {
      throw new NotSupportedException();
   }

   public function getId()
   {
       return $this->EmpId;
   }

   public function getAuthKey()
   {
       throw new NotSupportedException();
   }

   public function validateAuthKey($authKey)
   {
       throw new NotSupportedException();
   }

   public static function findByUsername($username)
   {
           return self::findOne(['Username'=>$username]);
   }

   public function validatePassword($password)
   {
   return $this->Password === $password;
   }
4. And in LoginForm model, I have following. Insted of User, I have included 
   custom class Employee.

   public function getUser()
   {
       if ($this->_user === false) 
       {
           $this->_user = Employee::findByUsername($this->username);
       }

   ```
   return $this->_user;
   ```

   }

Now when I try to login and provide username and password, it gives the foll error:

Unknown Property – yii\base\UnknownPropertyException

Getting unknown property: app\models\Employee::username

Answer (score 0):

Notice the Case in the column names in your - this should be the same as attributes in your model. 
ie: replace - 
$this->usename to $this->Username;